# Collection.sort not sorting properly in JDK 8 after implementing useLegacyMergesort to true

Tags: java, mergesort

I am upgrading one project from JDK 7 to JDK 8, where initially we encounter an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its
>   general contract!
>               at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(Unknown Source)
>               at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
>               at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(Unknown Source)
>               at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
>               at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
>               at java.util.ArrayList.sort(Unknown Source)
>               at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)

That we resolved with using System properties of **java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort** as **true**. After which exception was resolved but sorting that it performing is wrong(Improper sorting).

Note: In JDK 7 same code work perfectly(without this System properties)

```
public class SortTableModelRowComparator implements Comparator<TableModelSortingRow>
{   
    private boolean   ascending = true;
    protected int[]   sortingColumns;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     */
    public SortTableModelRowComparator(boolean pSortAscendending, int[] pSortingColumns)
    {
        ascending=pSortAscendending;
        sortingColumns=pSortingColumns;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(TableModelSortingRow o1,
            TableModelSortingRow o2) {
        BigDecimal firstvalue=(BigDecimal)o1.getValue(7);
        BigDecimal secondvalue=(BigDecimal)o2.getValue(7);

        return firstvalue.compareTo(secondvalue);
    }
}
```

Comment: We know neither what type you are sorting, nor what instances, nor what comparator you are using to sort them.

Comment: Added the comparator class. Could you please suggest something.

Comment: What does `getValue(7)` do?

Comment: It provide an object like BigDecimal

Comment: How does it provide it?  Does it calculate it?  Is it guaranteed to always return the same value every time?

Answer (score 4):

That is the problem with using that flag.

The original exception means that there is something wrong with your `Comparator` or `Comparable`'s comparison operation.  Something about it is violating the `Comparable` contract<sup>1</sup> that a valid comparison *needs* to obey.  Essentially, it is a bug in your application.

When you set that flag, you are telling the JVM to ignore the problem.  In some cases, you can get away with this.  In others ... like yours ... the consequences will be in incorrect sort.

Solution: Figure out why you were getting the exception, and fix that problem.

Note it could be a problem in the comparison itself, or it could be that something is mutating the objects while they are being sorted, and that is what causes the contract violation.

---

> Note: In JDK 7 same code work perfectly(without this System properties)

The sort algorithms used in Java 7 & Java 8 are different<sup>2</sup>.  However, it may well be that you were getting incorrect sorts in Java 7, and you didn't notice it.

---

<sup>1 - The [`Comparator` contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) is as follows:</sup>

<sup>"In the foregoing description, the notation `sgn(expression)` designates the mathematical signum function, which is defined to return one of -1, 0, or 1 according to whether the value of expression is negative, zero or positive.</sup>

- <sup>The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`. (This implies that `compare(x, y)` must throw an exception *if and only if* `compare(y, x)` throws an exception.)</sup>
- <sup>The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: `((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0))` implies `compare(x, z)>0`.</sup>
- <sup>Finally, the implementor must ensure that `compare(x, y)==0` implies that `sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z))` for all `z`."</sup>

<sup>2 - In addition, in Java 7 the implementation of the algorithm doesn't check for incorrect behavior in the comparison operation.  That explains why you got no exception in Java 7.</sup>

Comment: I added my comparator and related files for sorting with my question. Could you please see and let me know what could be the issue.

Comment: "something is mutating the objects while they are being sorted" Can you please explain it.

Comment: Mutating == changing.  Is that what you didn't understand?